# Using Provider Inside firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged return undefined

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, firebase-authentication

I try to call to a function that it a part from Provider, but I noticed that when 
the call is inside  `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` function all the providers are undefined.

@Ionic3.9.2
@cordova-8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)

That's my Code :

```
constructor(public global:global,public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public app: App, public dataProvider: DataProvider,
        public loadingProvider: LoadingProvider, public alertProvider: AlertProvider, public alertCtrl: AlertController, public firebaseProvider: FirebaseProvider, public modalCtrl: ModalController) { }

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        console.log(this.dataProvider);




        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
            if (user) {
                // User is signed in.
                console.log(user);
                this.currentUser=user;
                this.tab = "friends";
                this.title = "Friends";

                this.searchFriend = '';

                console.log(this.dataProvider); /*   -> undefined*/
                if (this.dataProvider.getRequests(this.currentUser != null)) {  /* the console return to me an error  :TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRequests' of undefined */
                    console.log(this.dataProvider.getRequests(this.currentUser));
                    // console.log(this.dataProvider.getRequests(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid));
                    console.log("if ");

                    // console.log(this.currentUser.uid);
                    console.log(this.currentUser);
                    this.dataProvider.getRequests(this.currentUser.uid).snapshotChanges().subscribe((requestsRes) => {
                        let requests = requestsRes.payload.val();
                        console.log(requests);
                        if (requests != null) {
                            if (requests.friendRequests != null && requests.friendRequests != undefined)
                                this.friendRequestCount = requests.friendRequests.length;
                            else this.friendRequestCount = 0
                        }
                        else this.friendRequestCount = 0;
                        console.log(this.friendRequestCount);
                    });

                    this.getFriends();
                }
            } else {
                // No user is signed in.
                console.log('no User');
            }
        });
```

I am sure that I miss something and be grateful for some help Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution

Explanation:
It's all about "this" keyword

this.dataProvider in the callback is not the same this.dataProvider outside the callback function.

To refer to the same this.dataProvider inside and outside the callback function, you just need to create a function and pass the dataProvider as a parameter.

```
constructor(public global:global,public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public app: App, public dataProvider: DataProvider,
        public loadingProvider: LoadingProvider, public alertProvider: AlertProvider, public alertCtrl: AlertController, public firebaseProvider: FirebaseProvider, public modalCtrl: ModalController) { 
this.ionViewDidLoad(this.dataProvider); // <--- with this (mandatory)
}
    ionViewDidLoad(dataProvider: DataProvider) {
        console.log(dataProvider); // <-- defined with or without this
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
         .........

                console.log(dataProvider); /* without this  -> NOT undefined anymore :) */

       })
```